# Indent table with Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I've been using bootstrap for a while now but I can't do this thing (I don't even know how to do it without Bootstrap).
What I want to is is indent either a table or divs. I've seen something like this done in Bootstrap with `<li>` but nothing with tables. Basically I want a table with the `<th>` which is the title and below the names of the projects. The reason I need to indent is because the projects depend on other projects; so the project below anoher project has to be possitioned slightly to the right of its parent (which is basically indenting, right?)

Comment: Please don't include "Hope I explained myself. Sorry for my English; it's not my native language. Any clue on how to do this? Thanks in advance." in your question. Our style focuses on the question, not on pleasantries.

Comment: A code posted with wat you are working on  will help us visualize well and give ya some sort of help.

Comment: Maybe a `<table>` is not what you are looking for : look at the [media objects](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#media) (note: images are optional). An example of what you tried even without indenting would be nice.

Answer (score 4):

Here are a couple options if what you need is a small indentation to suggest a hierarchy. They're not specific to Bootstrap tables.

The first is to add a couple nonbreaking spaces per level of indent that you want. This has the *advantage* that the spaces can be added by whatever code is producing the table content without disturbing the html of the table. It has the *disadvantage* that if the text wraps within the cell the wrapped lines will not be indented. Also, all those invisible nonbreaking spaces can lead to copy/paste surprises.

```
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;Indented Text</td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Indented More</td>
```

If your code is emitting the html of the table, a better solution is to change the padding of the table cell by increasing amounts. It has the *advantage* of finer control than increments of nonbreaking space, and wrapped text is also indented. The *disadvantage* here is you're emitting html from code and that may make it more difficult to adjust the layout.

```
<td style="padding-left:20px">Indented Text</td>
<td style="padding-left:40px">Indented More</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Could this be solved using offsets? It's somewhat difficult to help when we dont know the situation or how the markup is looking.

The offset* class will add a margin-left to your element. Maybe that will help you?